# How do I center a group of divs that stay centered if you change your resolution

Tags: css, html, alignment, center

I have to make a website for school and I'd like to know how to align these divs to the center so that the distance between them as it is now stays the same whatever you do but when you enlarge your browser window they stay centered at the bottom of the page as a group. Can anyone help me?

```
<div id="thing 1">
   <div style="position: absolute; bottom: 0px; left: 220px; width: 300px;">
   <img border="0" src="thing 1" alt="awesome thing 1" width="296,4" height="464,5">
</div>

<div id="thing 2">
   <div style="position: absolute; bottom: 0px; left: 470px; width: 300px;">
   <img border="0" src="thing 2" alt="awesome thing 2" width="228" height="357,3">
</div> 

<div id="thing 3">
   <div style="position: absolute; bottom: 0px; left: 700px; width: 300px;">
   <img border="0" src="thing 3" alt="awesome thing 3" width="90" height="400">
</div> 

<div id="thing 4">
   <div style="position: absolute; bottom: 0px; left: 820px; width: 300px;">
   <img border="0" src="thing 4" alt="awesome thing 4" width="200" height="380">
</div>
```

Comment: You missing closing `>` after your div id's. That just a side note.

Comment: @FLCL I recommend you not editing the closing `>` in. The author or another visitor won't learn from the possible mistakes this way. Intenting is okay.

Comment: @Tip_Top In the first place, editing other posts should not remove essential mistakes made by the original author. This _might_ just be the issue. In this case it's not, but who knows? Just leave the message like Morpheus and let the author fix his stuff.

Comment: You're right @Tip_Top but I couldn't find anything I quite understood so I thought I'd try this and luckily it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is leave the images in one div and add `text-align: center` styling to it:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="thing_1">
    <img border="0" src="thing 1" alt="awesome thing 1" width="296,4" height="464,5">
    <img border="0" src="thing 2" alt="awesome thing 2" width="228" height="357,3">
    <img border="0" src="thing 3" alt="awesome thing 3" width="90" height="400">
    <img border="0" src="thing 4" alt="awesome thing 4" width="200" height="380">
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#thing_1 {
    text-align: center;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/EDskx/)

Comment: Thanks for suggested edit @kleinfreund

Comment: thanks a lot Morpheus and @kleinfreund this was exactly what I was looking for and my code even looks better now. You guys are the best!

Answer (score 0):

```
.mydivs {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50px; /*some fixed width*/
}

/* centered equidistantly */
```

Comment: I'm probably just dumb but I put this in my style part and nothing rally happened. Should I have done anything else/differently?

Comment: Impossible to answer like this, make a JSFiddle

Comment: itcouldevenbeaboat assumed you know what to do with this. `.mydivs` is a class selector, but you don't have applied any class in your html. If you add `class="mydivs"` to your divs like you did with the ID's, it'd work fine.